# Need to draw two circles with same origin( same center point) using CSS styles

Tags: css, animation, styles, css-animations

I have a requirement to display 2 circles with different widths and heights but circles should start from same origin ( same center ), it means even though I change the sizes of both the circles they should look same with different sizes.

[image]

I have seen some bunch of examples over internet,problem with them is when I change the width and heights center point of both the circles are not the same anymore.

Also when I do hover they have to increase the size with smooth transition.

I am guessing that I need two circles to draw something like this, if we can draw with using only one circle please let me know.

Outer circle details:

inner circle

```
width: 97.33px;
height: 97.33px;
color: #DEBF43;
opacity: 74%;
shadow: #D7E0F1, 100%;
blur: 30px;
x - 0px //no idea but is mentioned in requirement
y 10px //no idea but is mentioned in requirement
```

outer circle details:

```
width: 79.49
height: 79.49
shadow: #000000,15%;
blur: 6px;
opacity: 100%;
X - 0px //no idea but is mentioned in requirement
y - 1px //no idea but is mentioned in requirement
```

Thanks,
   Rohan

Comment: A single element could be used to draw this via box-shadow or radial-gradient. but what about the animation and is there any content ?

Comment: for animation he can use transisition on css.

Comment: for a single element , here is what i mean : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EMgKEr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) with **[circles](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle)**. It is quite easy and well readable.
Get two circles aligned with different radius and manipulate them via Javascript. Just overwrite the `r`-property.

Here a quick example with Vue:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    r1: 120,
    r2: 90,
  }
});
```

```css
/* circles */

.circle--1 {
  fill: yellow;
}

.circle--2 {
  fill: orange;
}

.transparent {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

/* demo stuff */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100vh;
}

.svg, aside {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4rem #00000033;
  margin: 1rem;
}

aside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
   display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<main id="app" class="container">

  <!-- svg with two circles -->

  <svg class="svg" width="300" height="300">
    <circle class="circle circle--1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
    <circle class="circle circle--2" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="90"/>
  </svg>
  
  
  <!-- demo svg with editable radii -->
  
  <svg class="svg" width="300" height="300">
    <circle id="circle-1" class="circle circle--1 transparent" cx="50%" cy="50%" :r="r1" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
    <circle id="circle-2" class="circle circle--2 transparent" cx="50%" cy="50%" :r="r2"/>
  </svg>
  
  
  <!-- demo controls -->
  
  <aside>
    <section>
        <label for="radius1">Radius 1 ({{r1}}px)</label>
        <input type="range" id="radius1" min="0" max="140" v-model="r1">
    </section>
    <section>
      <label for="radius2">Radius 2 ({{r2}}px)</label>
      <input type="range" id="radius2" min="0" max="140" v-model="r2">
     </section>    
  </aside>  
  
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple idea where you can rely on multiple background. The trick is to make the gradient to cover only the content box and control the space using padding:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:5px solid;
  padding:20px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(orange,orange) content-box,
    yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Or like this with a `radial-gradient`

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:5px solid;
  padding:20px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,orange 60%,yellow 61%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```